# where clause sub query using avg

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, food and score.

Food

- `id`
- `name`
- `picture`

score

- `id`
- `score`
- `food_id`.

I want to query food that have average score above 7:

```
select * from food where (select avg(score) from score group by food_id)>=7
```

But this returns

> error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
select fd.* from food fd
inner join score sc on fd.id=sc .food_id
group by food.id
having avg(sc.score)>=7
```

Comment: so the key is to join them. i thought its not necessary because i dont select from score table. so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  SELECT * FROM food f INNER JOIN score s
  ON f.id = s.food_id
  WHERE avg(s.score)>=7
  GROUP BY f.food_id
```